# Formatting JSON for Google Charts API

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, object

Using MongoDB / Node consider the following payload:

```
    var myObj = {
            "date" : "1-23-45",
            "one" : [
                    {
                            "a" : 8
                    },
                    {
                            "b" : 1
                    },
                    {
                            "c" : 9
                    },
                    {
                            "d" : 10
                    },
                    {
                            "e" : 12424
                    },
                    {
                            "f" : 11
                    },
                    {
                            "g" : 7
                    }
            ],
            "two" : [
                    {
                            "h" : 6
                    },
                    {
                            "i" : 10
                    }
            ]
    },
{
            "date" : "1-24-45",
            "one" : [
                    {
                            "a" : 8
                    },
                    {
                            "b" : 1
                    },
                    {
                            "c" : 9
                    },
                    {
                            "d" : 10
                    },
                    {
                            "e" : 12424
                    },
                    {
                            "f" : 11
                    },
                    {
                            "g" : 7
                    }
            ],
            "two" : [
                    {
                            "h" : 6
                    },
                    {
                            "i" : 10
                    }
            ]
    }
```

I am using Google Charts API and I would like to plot these points to a line graph. **(see snippet)**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
            'modules':[{
              'name':'visualization',
              'version':'1',
              'packages':['corechart']
            }]
          }"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    var myObj = {
      "cols": [{
        "id": "",
        "label": "year",
        "type": "string"
      }, {
        "id": "",
        "label": "sales",
        "type": "number"
      }, {
        "id": "",
        "label": "expenses",
        "type": "number"
      }],
      "rows": [{
        "c": [{
          "v": "2001"
        }, {
          "v": 3
        }, {
          "v": 5
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2002"
        }, {
          "v": 5
        }, {
          "v": 10
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2003"
        }, {
          "v": 6
        }, {
          "v": 4
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2004"
        }, {
          "v": 8
        }, {
          "v": 32
        }]
      }, {
        "c": [{
          "v": "2005"
        }, {
          "v": 3
        }, {
          "v": 56
        }]
      }]
    }


    function drawChart() {


      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(myObj);
      var options = {
        title: 'My Chart',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: {
          position: 'right'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Using the JSON I am provided, what would be the most effective way to massage the data into the format accepted by Google Charts API? I have looked into D3 but it seemed to have a higher learning curve, would that be the most recommended route? Would it be better to query the dataset differently / aggregate the result?

Help is much appreciated, as this has been a 2 day long venture!

Update --
TL;DR
I need a script that goes from Format #1 => Format #2, no matter how big the payload is.

Format #1 - myObj

Format #2 -

```
var myObj = {
  "cols": [{
      "label": "Date",
      "type": "string"
    }, {
      "label": "a",
      "type": "number"
    }, {
      "label": "b",
      "type": "number"
    }, {
      "label": "c",
      "type": "number"
    }, {
      "label": "d",
      "type": "number"
    }, {
      "label": "e",
      "type": "number"
    }, {
      "label": "f",
      "type": "number"
    }, {
      "label": "g",
      "type": "number"
    }, {
      "label": "h",
      "type": "number"
    }, {
      "label": "i",
      "type": "number"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [{
      "c": [{
        "v": "day1"
      }, {
        "v": 300
      }, {
        "v": -500
      }, {
        "v": 23
      }, {
        "v": 120
      }, {
        "v": 150
      }, {
        "v": 1210
      }, {
        "v": 160
      }, {
        "v": 180
      }, {
        "v": 190
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "day2"
      }, {
        "v": 1300
      }, {
        "v": -5200
      }, {
        "v": 253
      }, {
        "v": 6120
      }, {
        "v": 1350
      }, {
        "v": 110
      }, {
        "v": 2160
      }, {
        "v": 1180
      }, {
        "v": 1190
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why the down votes? I appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your data and how it needs to be formatted, something like the below would work. You will need to loop over each object to get the **cols** and then map over each array to get the **rows**.

```
var dataObj = {
    "cols": [],
    "rows": []
};

for(property in myObj) {
    if(typeof myObj[property] === 'string') {
        dataObj.cols.push({
            "label": property,
            "type": "string"
        });
    } else {
        dataObj.rows.push({
            "c": []
        });

        dataObj.rows[dataObj.rows.length - 1]["c"].push({
            "date": "day" + dataObj.rows.length // The day: 1, 2, 3, etc.
        });

        myObj[property].map(function(object) {
            for(prop in object) {
                dataObj.cols.push({
                    "label": prop,
                    "type": "number"
                });

                dataObj.rows[dataObj.rows.length - 1]["c"].push({
                    "v": object[prop]
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle with Google Chart example](http://jsfiddle.net/fbxqw8m9/) (Open Console to see formatted data)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!! the data returned is prefect! I threw it inside my example and the page displays "Table has no columns" though.

Comment: Edit -- Nevermind stupid mistake, there are no errors, just an empty graph. Also, the legend shows 'one' 'two', I would like to graph the children of one/two over time, one/two should be ignored. Example - a over time / b over time etc

Comment: @Dnwebdev So **one** would be your start date and **two** would be your end date?

Comment: I have added bounty for you @Enijar

Comment: I wonder why you use Array.prototype.map(...) instead of Array.prototype.forEach(...) since you eventually don't map anything